# Physics class 11 Vector

Tags: vectors

Q.   Two boys raising a load pull at an angle to each other.  If the exerts forces of 30N and 60 N respectively and their effective pull is at the right angle to the direction of the pull of the first boy, then what is the angle between their arms ? What is their effective pull?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer down votes if you show that you've mad an effort to solve the problem yourself.  What have you tried so far?  Where are you stuck?  Be sure to add your response to the question body, **not** to the comments.

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to MSE. You will receive more up votes if you show an effort being made with your problem. I would edit your question to show your work so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$$\text{Angle between two Forces} = 90 + \sin^{-1}(\frac{30}{60}) = 120 \ \text {deg}$$

$$R = \sqrt{60^2 - 30^2} = 51.962N$$